# AutoDesk Maya MEL - iPhone Facecap transfer issue

Tags: maya, mel

I am trying to copy facial motion data, head rotation specifically, gathered through an app called FaceCap via iPhone and transfer to Maya models.

I've gotten the data to successfully transfer but... the rotation is an exact mirror of original facial motion data.

Here's the code so far:

// rotation X copied

```
select -r grp_transform ;
selectKey -clear ;
selectKey -add -k grp_transform_rotateX;
copyKey ;
```

//rotation X pasted

```
select -r H_DDS_HighRes ;
selectKey -clear ;
pasteKey -time 1 -float 1 -option merge -copies 1 -connect 0 -timeOffset 0 
    floatOffset 0 -valueOffset 0 {"Head.rx"};
```

How do I make an exact transfer of data instead of mirroring it?